# AngularJS Factory functions that interact with each other

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJS Factory that is an upload, I'm trying to make the progress fire a function called `progressState` but it's not working.

Is there anyway of getting this to work?

```
myApp.factory('fooFactory', function() {

    return {
        upload: function(foo){
            upload(foo)
            .progress(evt){
               progressState(evt, state);
            }
        },
        progressState: function(evt, state){
            return fooVar;
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `this`

outside return

```
 var self = this;
```

inside return

```
self.progressState(evt, state);
```

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'progressState' of undefined`

Comment: Now that returns `undefined is not a function`

Comment: "fooVar" is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

I have mocked up the best I can without access to your upload function, does this help

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('fooFactory', function() {
    var factory = {};  
    factory.upload = function(foo){
          console.log ('factory : ' , factory)
          factory.progressState();
        }
  
    factory.progressState = function(){
          console.log('progress state called')
    }
    
    return factory;
});

myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'fooFactory', function($scope, fooFactory){
  $scope.test = 'controller active';
 
  fooFactory.upload();
  
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <p>{{test}}</p>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah and it returns `undefined is not a function`

Comment: I have written a mockup which might help you